# How to return a value from an Observable?

Tags: angular, observable

I have this method and I would like to return true/false from it, but I am getting this error: `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.`

```js
  public isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const url = `${this.endPoint}/me`;
    this.http.get<any>(url).subscribe(
      () => {
        return true;
      },
      () => {
        return false;
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is quite a misunderstanding of Observables and TypeScript here.

You can save the value returned from the observable to a property

```js
  public isLoggedIn: boolean;
  public loadIsLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const url = `${this.endPoint}/me`;
    this.http.get<any>(url).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
      },
      () => {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      }
    );
  }
```

Another option is to use a promise

```js
  public async loadIsLoggedIn(): Promise<boolean> {
    const url = `${this.endPoint}/me`;
    try {
       return await this.http.get<any>(url);
    } catch {
       return false
    }
  }
```

`async` pipe usually is the best option. The provided code is not enough to provide a sample for your case. I would you can manage to figure out its usage.

Comment: This is a known issue with a known duplicate that's been used thousands of times. Please refrain from answering duplicates like these.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the logic in your method to return an Observable

```js
 public isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    const url = `${this.endPoint}/me`;
    return this.http.get<any>(url)
      .pipe(
        // map operator is called when the HTTP call is successful
        map(() => true),
        // catchError operator is called when the HTTP call encounters an error
        catchError((error) => of(false))
      );
  }
```

And you can subscribe to it where you need the boolean value

Answer (score 0):

You can work with what you get from `Observable` like this:

```
public isLoggedIn: boolean;

...

this.httpService.isLoggedIn()
 .subscribe(
   (result) => {
     this.isLoggedIn = true;
   },
   (error) => {
     this.isLoggedIn = false;
   }
);
```

```
isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {   
  const url = `${this.endPoint}/me`;
  return this.http.get<any>(url);
}
```